# Get all recommended keg-only environment variables

Tags: homebrew

As I'm going through a bit of cleanup / rebuild on my homebrew, I'm watching a bunch of messages like this go by:

```
This formula is keg-only: so it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

Mac OS X already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
build variables:

    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include
```

I am very likely to build software that I would like to link against the homebrew versions as opposed to the OS X versions. I am also very unlikely to remember which libraries were keg-only, or track them down appropriately during some late-night `./configure; make; make install` session.

Is there a way for Homebrew to cough up a list of all such flags (perhaps in an easy-to-set environment variable format) for those times when I'd like to be reminded of all my keg-only libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really.

If this concerns you, the best fix would be to set up your own software as a Homebrew formula, because that build process will automatically include the include and link paths for all keg-only packages.  (Look up "superenv" for details.)